# Поиск элемента в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть задача. Имеется строка, например: "Thank you for registering. Your id: gyro-634-test. You can see our project."
Из неё нужно получить "gyro-634-test". Данный id может быть разным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var s = "Thank you for registering. Your id: gyro-634-test. You can see our project."
console.log(s.match(/id:\s*(\S+)\./)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с более примитивной регуляркой, но и менее стабильный чем у @Qwertiy

```js
let str= 'Thank you for registering. Your id: gyro-634-test. You can see our project.';
console.log(str.split(/:|\./)[2])
```